# While loop with single quotes for a condition in Python

Tags: python, while-loop

I came across the following line of code in Python and I keep wondering what does it do exactly:

```
while '' in myList:
    myList.remove('')
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It removes all empty strings from a list, inefficiently.

`'' in myList` tests if `''` is a member of `myList`; it'll loop over `myList` to scan for the value. `myList.remove('')` scans through `myList` to find the first element in the list that is equal to `''` and remove it from the list:

```
>>> myList ['', 'not empty']
>>> '' in myList
True
>>> myList.remove('')
>>> myList
['not empty']
>>> '' in myList
False
```

So, the code repeatedly scans `myList` for empty strings, and each time one is found, another scan is performed to remove that one empty string.

```
myList = [v for v in myList if v != '']
```

would be a different, more efficient way of accomplishing the same task. This uses a list comprehension; loop over all values in `myList` and build a *new* list object from those values, provided they are not equal to the empty string.

Comment: As you note, the rewrite is not equivalent to the original code - since it creates a new list, if the list was shared, the other places will continue to see the old list with all the empty strings. To fix this, use slice assignment: `myList[:] = (v for v in myList if v != '')`.

Answer (score 1):

Put simply, it removes all empty strings from `myList`.

Below is a breakdown:

```
# While there are empty strings in `myList`...
while '' in myList:
    # ...call `myList.remove` with an empty string as its argument.
    # This will remove the one that is currently the closest to the start of the list.
    myList.remove('')
```

---

Note however that you can do this a lot better (more efficiently) with a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
myList = [x for x in myList if x != '']
```

or, if `myList` is purely a list of strings:

```
# Empty strings evaluate to `False` in Python
myList = [x for x in myList if x]
```

---

If `myList` is a list of strings and you are on Python 2.x, you can use [`filter`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#filter), which is even shorter:

```
myList = filter(None, myList)
```

Comment: @Konos5 - Pieters explained it pretty well, but using a list comprehension is more efficient because it only runs through the list _once_, not multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

In Python, two single quotes `''` or double quotes `""` represent the empty string.

The condition to keep looping is `while` the empty string exists in the list, and will only terminate when there are no more empty strings.

Therefore, it removes all empty strings from a list.